# Definition of conjugate symmetry for arbitrary inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra

I've gone through the definition of inner product space. One of the axioms for the inner product is conjugate symmetry.

$\langle u, v\rangle = \overline{\langle v, u\rangle}$

The vector space in most of the textbooks and resources is defined as either real or complex vector space in which the conjugate is well-defined.

What is the definition of a conjugate of an element in an arbitrary field?

Thanks

Comment: In mathematics, in particular field theory, the conjugate elements of an algebraic element α, over a field extension L/K, are the roots of the minimal polynomial pK,α(x) of α over K. Conjugate elements are also called Galois conjugates or simply conjugates. Normally α itself is included in the set of conjugates of α.

https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Conjugate_element_(field_theory)#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20in%20particular%20field,set%20of%20conjugates%20of%20%CE%B1.

Comment: @khanh "Conjugacy" is a relationship between elements in a field $L$  that extends a subfield $K$. The fact that complex numbers have exactly one conjugate element is a consequence of the fact that $\Bbb C$ is a degree-$2$ extension of the subfield $\Bbb R$; more generally, one element will have several conjugate elements.